# Can Webform CIviCRM module do Line Items (PS yes it can!)

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

How can we sell a Membership and a Calendar (that we should charge Sales tax on) and let the user make a Donation all on the same Webform Civicrm page - in a way that only the Donation amount is eligible to receive a charitable tax receipt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of last week you can now create Additional Line Items with webform civicrm module (which is a Drupal/CiviCRM integration module). Coleman and I are thankful to Wilderness Committee (Canada) for sponsoring this new feature!

1. if you'd like to try this out before a next dev-release - you can download the latest webform_civicrm code from: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm.git
2. with the latest code in your Webform -> navigate to your CiviCRM tab -> Contribution tab and you'll see the new Configuration option 'Additional Line Items' at the bottom of that tab. In this example we'll use two and we'll let the user select their own financial type (of course you can configure that to any static financial type as well and/or hide these fields from the form the usual webform civicrm way)

[image]

3. Configure the new fields -> We need to charge Sales Tax on the Calendar - while ensuring the Donation is of type Donation so that it becomes eligible for a Charitable Tax Receipt. We have also configured the form such that the user can add a Membership (and be charged the proper amount for it).

[image]

4. View/fill out the webform:
   [image]
5. Next Page:

[image]

6. Contribution created in CiviCRM!

[image]

Comment: This sounds great.  Perhaps you should make it clear that this only works with Drupal though.

Comment: Yes - Webform CiviCRM is a Drupal module.

Comment: This is not the same as Line Items as currently used in CiviCRM Price Sets?

Comment: These are more flexible in that you can create them on tbe webform as needed;

Comment: Actually we’re calling them Line Items because they are stored in the civicrm_line_item table

Comment: I deleted my comments about the tables not getting properly filled. I have setup our donation page using the new line item capabilities and my reports are all still working--using Extended Reports.  Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Thank you for looping back - glad to hear you got line items working

Comment: I think there might be a minor issue that if you edit the options in the line item component and then re-edit it does not show the settings that you have saved but instead shows you all of them as selected which is confusing

Comment: Is there a way to populate the line item with a value stored in a custom field that is unique to member? I have a custom field civicrm_2_contact_1_cg11_custom_32 that holds past due amount that I'd like to add to the total check out. Maybe this is a new question?

Comment: Yes ask a new question! And I’ll give you some examples for that.

Comment: Should this work in D7/Backdrop as well? I am seeing a form with line items lumping it all together in the CiviCRM backend even though the webform shows the separate line items.

Comment: Sorry - I’m afraid I don’t know about Backdrop.

Comment: It seems as though resulting contributions aren't fully compatible with civi core, webform_civicrm uses the default quick config price set for line items, and when there are multiple line items things can go wrong. I've posted more details [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45602/trouble-with-editing-contributions-with-multiple-line-items), @KarinG-SemperIT I'd love your input!

Comment: Hi Aiden! We’re just using the API to create line items - and quick config is ok but you’re saying CiviCRM can only handle one quick config line item but not two? Write it up in an issue on drupal.org with a scenario that we can reproduce and Jitendra and I can look into it.

Comment: Thanks @KarinG-SemperIT, I have done so [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3390363)